# Connection refused. Unable to connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to launch my jupyter notebook on the instance created. It is not  connecting to the address.

I thought it was an internet connection issue but it is not.
I have deleted the instance previously created for a new one and still has the same issue.
I created a new set of firewall rules, but did not help.

Comment: I think it would help to add more context to your question, as it's a bit unclear at the moment. Please also have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So I created a virtual machine in GCP. I use jupyter notebook for my machine learning work. So when I try to load my jupyter notebook through the ssh. When  I tried to do that, it gives me the connection error.

Comment: Can you please provide the below information to investigate further:
- How are you trying to connect to the instance?
- What error your are getting? Please provide the full details or the screenshot of the error?
- What firewall rules have you created

Comment: The following is the image: https://imgur.com/wTWvPpZ
Also the firewall setting is nothing but a port for connecting to my jupyter notebook. The following is the article which explains the typical process that I did: https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue with the [instructions](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52) you have provided, its working fine for me. Please confirm the below steps to configure it properly:

1. Make sure you open the TCP port 5000 mentioned in step 5.
2. You need to add this port number = 5000 in the Jupyter configuration file mentioned in step 8

To access the server you need to follow below steps:

1. Open a SSH terminal in your VM instance and run the below command to launch your jupyter notebook

   jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=5000

Note that: you need to keep this SSH session open while trying to access it via your browser, otherwise it won’t connect.

2. Open another terminal in the same VM instance and run the below command to see if 5000 port is listening

   netstat -tulpn
3. Then type the following in your browser:
   http:// [External Static IP Address]:5000

Comment: After launching jupyter and keeping it open, could you spin up another SSH session and run the command : "netstat -tulpn"? This command will show you if port 5000 is listening.